# why can't I insert text object into an element's innerHTML

Tags: javascript, appendchild, textnode, createtextnode

we can assign the input value to a variable and then we're assingning that variable to an element's innerHTML, likewise why can't I insert text object into an element's innerHTML??

eg code:

```js
x = document.getElementById("my_input"). value;
    
y = document.createElement("p");
    
y.innerHTML = x;
```

This code works but the below code isn't, why?

eg code:

```js
x = document.getElementById("my_input"). value;
    
    
y = document.createElement("p");
    
z = document.createTextNode("x");
    
y.innerHTML = z;
```

I'm a beginner in js.. Correct me if I'm wrong..thanks!!

Comment: Because z is a reference to an object, while x (in the first example) is just a string.

Comment: The value you read from the input field is a string, that you can assign to innerHTML. Your `z` in the second example however is not a string, it is a DOM node. Trying to assign that to innerHTML simply makes little sense. If you want to work with DOM methods, then you need to _append_ your new node to an existing element.

Comment: Because z references to an object `[object Text]`. Use `y.appendChild(z)` to add the element as child node.

Comment: @CBroe: Tq ,but I know these strings but don't have a idea of how the return type of createtextnode looks like..what this createtextnode return looks like ,can you give me a eg

Comment: It returns the new Text node it created, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text

Answer (score 1):

as you can read here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp
The innerHTML property can only be set to a string. Because `z` is a DOM object then it wont work as you expect. To add a DOM object you must use the `appendChild` method. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

It all comes down to types. One propery is of type string so you should not pass an object to it.

```js
const x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

const y = document.createElement("p");

const z = document.createTextNode(x);

// you need to append child, cause x is a DOM object, not a string
y.appendChild(z);

// just to show that the element actually worked
document.getElementById("myElement").appendChild(y);
```

```html
<input id="myInput" value="Hello world" /><br /> Div element:
<div id="myElement">

</div>
```