# How do i add a new element in a list element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, object, input, html-lists

I like to add an input field to my list element for the timer im working on.
The problem is that it can read the function but doesnt display the object.

```
//Input Element Object
function inputElement() {
    this.input = document.createElement("input");
    this.input.id = "Timer " + count
    this.input.type = "number";
    this.input.max = 10;
    this.input.min = 01;
}


function LI(id) {
    
    this.li = document.createElement("li");
    this.li.id = id; 
    this.li.id += count;
    this.input = new inputElement();
    this.li.innerHTML += this.input + ` set Timer`;

    this.setting = document.getElementById("Version3");
    this.setting.append(this.li);
    
   
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why can't I insert text object into an element's innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031868/why-cant-i-insert-text-object-into-an-elements-innerhtml)

Comment: Also, `this.input = new inputElement()` means that `this.input` contains an object that has another `.input` property. So you'll need `this.input.input`. Or you need to call it like `inputElement.apply(this)` so the `this` inside `inputElement()` refers to the same `this` inside `LI()`.

Comment: well the list is with all the text is showing, but the input object   still get an undefined.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/k0dqo9yx/